# Discord JS | Server: detect re-joined user

Tags: discord.js

I would like that my bot detect when a user is joining again, back, to the server. I have made a JSON file containing the ID of the users that left the server. If the new member's ID is included in the JSON file with IDs, then it (the bot) should give a special welcome message.
The code shown is not working, meaning it is not really taking any ID from the JSON file. I guess that it needs a bucle with the lenght of the JSON's content to compare the Member ID with Badmember.USERS_LEFT_ID[].

JSON file: `user_left.json`

```json
{
    "USERS_LEFT_ID" : [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
    ]
}
```

JS File: `guildMemberAdd.js`

```
const Badmember = require('users_left.json')
exports.run = async(client, newmember) => {
  const channel = newmember.guild.channels.cache.get(Wlc_ch);
  if (newmember.user.id == Badmember.USERS_LEFT_ID) {
     channel.send('Special message!')
  } else {
    console.log(newmember);
    console.log(newmember.user.id + ' has joined');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details, like what is not working for you, how you tried to solve it, what you think you will try next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if the user is in the ID list, need to somehow iterate through the array. One option is to use the built-in `includes()` method.

```js
const Badmember = require('users_left.json')
exports.run = async(client, newmember) => {
  const channel = newmember.guild.channels.cache.get(Wlc_ch);
  if (Badmember.USERS_LEFT_ID.includes(newmember.user.id)) {
     channel.send('Special message!')
  } else {
    console.log(newmember);
    console.log(newmember.user.id + ' has joined');
  }
}
```

Check out MDN docs for more details on `Array.prototype.includes()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes